# xcode 10 error: multiple commands produce - react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

So there are a lot of questions like this already, but I'm having the same error, **not** relating to cocoapods or info.plist, at least I don't think, because none of the solutions worked for me.

I just recently upgraded to Xcode 10.0, and building my react native app gives this error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-code/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/appname.app':
1) Target 'appname' has create directory command with output '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-code/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/appname.app'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'appname': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd start with cleaning your derived data... delete /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, then rebuild.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it by upgrading cocoapods to the latest version:

1. Close Xcode project.
2. Upgrade cocoapods to latest version - run "sudo gem install cocoapods"
3. Follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods) to remove existing pods
4. Run "pod install" in the project directory

Comment: I tried it but just this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451421/2238515 solved for me

Answer (score 18):

I have resolved my issue in Xcode 10.2 through below steps:

> change the build system to Legacy

**File > Workspace Settings > Build System > Legacy Build System.**

[image]

Comment: simplest solution

Comment: it worked, i had issue on Multiple commands produce error for /path... / .ttf file

Answer (score 1):

#### For those using React Native and Cocoapods

The issue was produced by some ***libRN...a*** files. I fixed it by removing some of them like libRNScreens.a and libRNGestureHandler.a from **Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries** since they were already being referenced from another libraries. Others had to be replaced by their Pod version like libRNDeviceInfo.a:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution was in removing all that `installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| ...` fixes from `Podfile` also I had `pod 'React', :path => '...` which I also removed. So my `Podfile` now looks like this

```rb
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'

target 'AppName' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

Default react-native `Podfile`

I was migrating from react-native `0.59` to `0.64`