# Pod init or pod update is giving the below error

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I am unable to use pod install or update. I have installed the cocoapods again and updated gems as well. Is there any way this can be resolved. I have spent a day on this but no luck.
This the error:

```
  Update all pods

   Updating local specs repositories
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods- 
   core/source/metadata.rb:15:in `initialize': undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<String:0x00007fa4df813c48> (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/metadata.rb:28:in `from_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:434:in `refresh_metadata'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:55:in `refresh_metadata'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:29:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:308:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:308:in `block in source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `source_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `map'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:324:in `aggregate_with_repos'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:24:in `aggregate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:58:in `all'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

just to be correct, [you've already uninstalled and reinstalled the Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods)? Because that solution always works for me.

Is this with Xcode or a different IDE?

Comment: I have installed gem 2.3 , then installed the latest cocoapods . Move to the project file and followed the steps mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods , but the last step 'pod init' i get the same error as mentioned in my question. Yes this is XCode.